# Debugging in VS Code

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I've been following this post about using *Debugger for Chrome* in VSCode: [How to debug Karma tests in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805028/how-to-debug-karma-tests-in-visual-studio-code).

My launch.json is this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "trace": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

And my Karma config has this:

```
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['ChromeDebugging'],
singleRun: true,
restartOnFileChange: true,
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeDebugging: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: ['--remote-debugging-port=4200']
  }
}
```

When I launch from the debug panel it goes directly to localhost:4200 but it's not hitting my breakpoints. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `attach` and not `launch` your debugger in chrome.

Launch.json

Change this line from `"request": "launch"` to `"request": "attach"`

Checkout this great [blog post for further details](http://blog.mlewandowski.com/Debugging-Karma-tests-with-VSCode.html)

Comment: Got it, thank you. But what if I want to debug not just my tests but everything else?

Comment: @fumeng that's a different question. But you can check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial#_debugging-angular. TLDR - You need to create a different debug-profile for that.